# How to configure HTTPs support for application running on Azure VM

Tags: azure, https, azure-virtual-machine, self-signed

I am running my custom application on Azure VM. Now I want to provide HTTPs support using Self-signed certification for my application.

I did the following

1. Generate a JKS file

> ```
> $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias test -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore sample.jks -dname "CN=test,OU=admin,O=sample,L=Redwood City,ST=CA,C=US" -storepass testing -keypass testing
> ```

2. Configure the following property file with above values

> ```
> redirect_port=443
> ssl_port=443
> keystore=sample.jks
> keystore_password=testing
> truststore=sample.jks
> truststore_password=testing
> ```

3. Add HTTPs port

> ```
> firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=https
> systemctl restart firewalld
>
> netstat -ln
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
> ```

4. When I load the https://myip , It keeps on loading and getting connection time out error after some time.

> This site can’t be reached
>   **myip** took too long to respond.

**Update:-**

I made it working by myself after adding 443 port in NSG rule. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 3 moving parts:

1. application listening (seems you got that covered).
2. OS level firewall allowing traffic (iptables\whatever)
3. Azure level firewall allowing traffic (network security group\firewall)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-vnet-plan-design-arm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/overview

Comment: I missed the 3rd one (NSG rule)